# Android Java Bitmap.getByteCount() showing larger size than actual size

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I downloaded an image file of size 5.8 KB into an ImageView for my Android App.I saved the image to my application directory using bitmap.compress() method. And as I wanted to know the size of the image I downloaded I used Bitmap.getByteCount() to get the size of the image.
Following is the code:
But here I am getting the size as 201.984 KB for an image whose actual size is just 5.8 KB.
Can anyone say me what is wrong?
Thaadvance!

Answer (score 1):

> But here I am getting the size as 201.984 KB

`Bitmap` is a decoded image. `getByteCount()` returns the size, in memory, of the decoded image.

> for an image whose actual size is just 5.8 KB

What you think the "actual size" appears to be the compressed size on disk. That is not the same as the size of the decoded image in memory, nor should it be.

Comment: So how do I get the compressed size?

Comment: @Ashfaq: If you want to find out the length of the file, call `length()` on a `File` pointing at that file.

Comment: I used file.length() but gives me 0.

Comment: @Ashfaq: Then you are calling `length()` before the file is completely written, presumably.

Comment: I am calling it after the file has saved: File fl=new File(fname); long size=fl.length();

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap and other format difference.

For Example Bitmap ARGB_8888
Every pixel contains alpha, red, green, blue channel. And than every changel size 8 bit.(0

Example :

Width = 50px
Height = 50px
Format = ARGB_8888
Size = 50 x 50 x 32bit(4byte) = 2500 x 4 = 10000 bytes